# exp init Project [11:31:26] zlib: unexpected end of file

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, exp

When I run `exp init Locations` it gives me this error:

[image]

npm: `6.1.0`

exp: `55.04`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @Mandan described.
You could also navigate to `%userprofile%/.expo/starter-app-cache` folder to delete blank-1.8.0.tar.gz, and run the `expo init` again

Answer (score 2):

This is because blank-31.0.1.tar.gz expo pakage does not downloaded properly.

go to `C:\Users\YourUsername\ .expo\starter-app-cache`     and delete  "blank-31.0.1.tar.gz".

After this run:

```
expo init awsome-project.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this can happen when expo caches a corrupt starter file (see [Issues](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/25)).

Try to delete the file at `~\.exponent\starter-app-cache\blank-1.8.0.tar.gz` and/or remove and reinstall exp using `npm remove -g exp` and `npm install -g exp`

Comment: I try npm remove -g exp and then npm install -g exp but it gives this error again

it gives when I choose the blank project in other option it doesn't give this error but I don't want second option