# can't extract react-native blank template for a new project

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to create a new project in react-native but I still can't because it ask me to choose a template for my project, when I choose blank template, it download it but it still can't extract it. it look like there's a problem with a file named 'zlib'. it's my first project in react-native and i'm new on it. please help me solve it! thanks.

Below is the screenshoot I got when execute the command 'create-react-native-app MoviesAndMe' in order to create a react-native app named 'MoviesAndMe'

Comment: please provide the error, there's no screenshot attached

Comment: I'm trying to add image but stackoverflow tell me that i might have 10 points of reputation befor start posting an image. But here is the cmd complete text : C:\Users\USFAA\Documents\react-native projects>create-react-native-app MoviesAndMe
? Choose a template: blank
[12:04:26] Extracting project files...
Process exited with non-zero code: 2
ERROR: Unexpected end of data : blank-31.0.1.tar

Process exited with non-zero code: 2
[12:04:26] zlib: unexpected end of file
[12:04:26] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.

C:\Users\USFAA\Documents\react-native projects>

Comment: check this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962464/exp-init-project-113126-zlib-unexpected-end-of-file

Comment: Thank you soo much kivul... this link solved my problem. :)

Comment: nice, glad to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exp init Project \[11:31:26\] zlib: unexpected end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962464/exp-init-project-113126-zlib-unexpected-end-of-file)